# Requests not arriving at my own nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I want to handle the dns requests for my own domain.
For example I have the domain `dnsrequest.me` and the nameserver is pointed towards my server `178.62.242.84` (whois confirms this).

So when someone does a dns request for `dnsrequest.me` for the first time **ever**, the dns request should arrive at `178.62.242.84` right? But it doesn't.

My server is listening for dns requests on port `port 53` and when I do a request to the server directly it does work. The following request arrives at my server.

```
dig @178.62.242.84 -t ANY dnsrequest.me
```

Nothing arrives on my serverwhen I do a nslookup

```
bash-4.3$ nslookup dnsrequest.me
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 8.8.8.8, trying next server
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find dnsrequest.me: NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: If at all possible, please name the domain and an existant host name. It's much easier to diagnose that way. http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts

Comment: @SvW Ok, done. My server will respond '1.1.1.1' to any A request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is an error in your DNS glue. When I do a query for dnsrequest.me at the .me authorative DNS servers they return an IP instead of a name:

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ dig -t ns dnsrequest.me @89.188.44.44

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> -t ns dnsrequest.me @89.188.44.44
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50716
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dnsrequest.me.         IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dnsrequest.me.      86400   IN  NS  178.62.242.84. <<IP address not allowed here
dnsrequest.me.      86400   IN  NS  178.62.242.83. <<IP address not allowed here

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 89.188.44.44#53(89.188.44.44)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 13 16:53:30 CEST 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 96
```

However, according to [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#page-17) the result of an NS query should be a hostname/fqdn (so an A record). This record can then point to a specific IP address, like so:

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ dig -t ns mtak.nl @194.146.106.42

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> -t ns mtak.nl @194.146.106.42
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24256
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mtak.nl.           IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mtak.nl.        7200    IN  NS  ns0.transip.net.    < NS records (to hostnames)
mtak.nl.        7200    IN  NS  ns1.transip.nl.     < NS records (to hostnames)
mtak.nl.        7200    IN  NS  ns2.transip.eu.     < NS records (to hostnames)

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.transip.nl.     7200    IN  A   80.69.69.69     < A records (to IP address)
ns1.transip.nl.     7200    IN  AAAA    2a01:7c8:b::53

;; Query time: 22 msec
;; SERVER: 194.146.106.42#53(194.146.106.42)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 13 16:55:17 CEST 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 163
```

It would be best to contact your registrar and have them update the records for you. The configuration should look like this:

```
dnsrequest.me.     IN NS ns1.dnsrequest.me.
dnsrequest.me.     IN NS ns2.dnsrequest.me.
ns1.dnsrequest.me. IN A 178.62.242.83
ns2.dnsrequest.me. IN A 178.62.242.84
```